# What is a Special PoS Word™?

Tags: word-property, language

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Special PoS Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Special PoS Words™ | Not Special PoS Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| ADVICE | ADVERB |
| PRACTICE | PRACTICAL |
| DEVICE | DEMISE |
| LICENCE | LENIENT |

CSV version:

```
Special PoS Words™, Not Special PoS Word™
ADVICE, ADVERB
PRACTICE, PRACTICAL
DEVICE, DEMISE
LICENCE, LENIENT
```

**Perhaps** these are the only such words exist in standard English.

Also, as a bonus, provide a reasonable expansion for PoS.

Comment: only PoS words or non-PoS words? (exist in standard English)

Comment: I feel like there's not enough examples for this puzzle - if there's only so many "such words" it may be a matter of adding more examples for the other side. I have a hunch, but (ROT13) ner bssrapr be qrsrapr fcrpvny cbf jbeqf?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, well a reasonable doubt. Only those many Special PoS words exist.

Comment: how many non-special PoS words exist?

Comment: No cap/limit on non-special PoS words :-), though !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A PoS word is ...

> One in which changing the last **C** to an **S** changes its **P**art **o**f **S**peech from a noun to the verb that matches that noun.

Thus,

> ADVICE → ADVISE
>  PRACTICE → PRACTISE
>  DEVICE → DEVISE
>  LICENCE → LICENSE

This apparently relies on

> the UK style spelling of some of the words, as in the US we don't use "practise" or "licence", and "practice" and "license" are used for either part of speech.

Comment: yes, you nailed it!

Comment: ...which might explain the TM suffix, which, in the UK, stands for 'Totally Meaningless'

Comment: This may make "prophecy" another example.

Answer (score 2):

I think a PoS word is:

> A Word in which you can change a "C" into an "S" and get another word.

Explanation:

> Practi**C**e-> Practi**S**e
>  and So on.

They are called PoS word because:

> Maybe, it has to do something with the **Position of "S"**

Comment: If this is MCN's intention then "Perhaps these are the only such words in standard English" is very, very wrong. back/bask, came/same, cane/sane, ...

Comment: Good attempt and answer as well. Got the underlying intention correctly, but not in full / complete, particularly expansion of PoS is to be looked at.